# Is it possible to place absolut positioned elements automatically among themselves?

Tags: css

Is it still possible to automatically place for examples `div` elements among themselves if they are positioned `absolut`?

In the code snippet there are three `div`elements which are placed among themselves. Is it somehow possible to delte the css style instructions for `#elem2` and `#elem3` and construct a general rule that the `div` elements should placed among themselves with an margin of e.g. `10px`? So that I can easily add new `div` elements (variable height) with the css class `column1` and don't have to worry about the `margin-top` respectively `margin-bottom`.

```css
#containerGraph {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:scroll;
}

/* set the position attribute for all div elements inside the mainContainer*/
#containerGraph > div {
    position: absolute;
}

.paramElement {
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 90px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    font-size: small;
}

.column1{
margin-left:10px;
}

#elem2{
 margin-top : 40px;
}

#elem3{
 margin-top : 117px;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerGraph" class="relative">

  <div class="paramElement column1" id="elem1">
    first
  </div>
  
  <div class="paramElement column1" id="elem2">
    second with very large text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
  
   <div class="paramElement column1" id="elem3">
    third
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange need, and I don't see how to solve it **the way the problem is posed**.

However it seems that, if an `absolute` position is needed, it should be relevant (and so useful) *only against the `containerGraph`*, but clearly not for each one among others.

So a solution might be to:

- insert a child `<div>` of your `containerGraph`, with an `absolute` position
- it will contain the (formerly `absolute`) other `<div>`s

You can see it working in this snippet:

```js
$('body').click(function() {
  $('#elem2').remove();
  $('#sub-container').append('<div  class="paramElement column1" id="elem4">fourth</div>');
});
```

```css
#containerGraph {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:scroll;
}

/* set the position attribute for all div elements inside the mainContainer*/
#containerGraph > div {
    position: absolute;
}

.paramElement {
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 90px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    font-size: small;
}

.column1{
margin-left:10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/*
#elem2{
 margin-top : 40px;
}

#elem3{
 margin-top : 117px;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click anywhere to change
<hr />
<div id="containerGraph" class="relative">
<div id="sub-container">
  <div class="paramElement column1" id="elem1">
    first
  </div>
  
  <div class="paramElement column1" id="elem2">
    second with very large text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
  
   <div class="paramElement column1" id="elem3">
    third
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```